# run a rule while not checking email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I am on Outlook 2013 - I want to run a rule while on vacation.  I can't seem to get away from the statement - this rule will run only when outlook is checked or running.  I need it to run when my lap top is off for 10 days

Comment: Why do you think you can run anything while your  computer is turned off?

Answer (score 0):

**Rules that only run when Outlook is running will run *only when Outlook is running*.** There are no workarounds for this behavior.

Outlook has two types of rules: those that can be carried out by the Exchange mail server and those that can **only** be executed by a local Outlook client. If your mail account isn't hosted by an Exchange server, then all of the rules must be executed on the Outlook client.

Outlook will indicate when you're configuring the rules if it must be run on the local client. If you're seeing this message, then Outlook **must be running** in order for the rule to run. If Outlook isn't running when the mail arrives, the rule will not execute until Outlook is next started.

There are no workarounds for this behavior--and for good reason. These rules work with information that is only known to the Outlook client. Without access to said information, the rule cannot carry out its configured action.

Comment: Thank you.  I should have said I am on a lap top at work and I have another rule that works - it doesn't come up as client only.  I need to somehow get rid of the client only.  This is a large corporation so I am def on a server.  Hard to understand my IT.

Comment: @Ginger edit your original question to include a screen shot or description of the rule that you're having trouble with.